# Old ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, package-management, dependencies

Explanation:

I have a VPS that comes with ubuntu 10.10. I'm using it for a webserver that runs a bunch of sites. My problem is that I cannot upgrade the distribution (which I really want) . I installed the needed software but at some point it start giving me problems. 
I think it is important to say that I changed to source.list from maverick to natty. So basicly I just copy the source list of natty and put it into the place of maverick.

THen I was able to install apache, php and etc.

Now when I try to install something it always gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.4 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 g++-4.5 : Depends: gcc-4.5 (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.3-12ubuntu2 is installed
 gcc-4.5 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is installed
           Depends: cpp-4.5 (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is installed
           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 1:4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is installed
           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-0ubuntu13.2) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 libmpfr4 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 libnih-dbus1 : Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) but 1.0.3-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
root@348588:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.4 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 g++-4.5 : Depends: gcc-4.5 (= 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) but 4.5.3-12ubuntu2 is installed
 gcc-4.5 : Depends: gcc-4.5-base (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is installed
           Depends: cpp-4.5 (= 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is installed
           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.5.3-12ubuntu2) but 1:4.5.2-8ubuntu4 is installed
           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-0ubuntu13.2) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 libmpfr4 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-0ubuntu13.2 is installed
 libnih-dbus1 : Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) but 1.0.3-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

it is dependency problem. I read a bunch of articles from this website but none of them help me.

Does anyone have a solution for the problem?
Thanks

Comment: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.` it says in the message ;)

Comment: However, this might help you: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/114818).

Comment: After changing the sources.list did you do: 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'?

Comment: yes, I made both

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try as noted in the output `apt-get install -f`
2. If this does not help, try to get back in a consistent state by removing the problematic packages for a while .
3. Start with `apt-get upgrade` before you do a `apt-get dist-upgrade`. With a little bit luck you avoid some problematic dependency dead-locks this way.
4. Try to update the `libc6` package with `apt-get install libc6` and look at the output to get a glue which packages are forcing the *old* version of the libc6 package.